# How to launch viber in i3wm?

Tags: linux, viber, i3

I've been using i3wm for a while. But now I need viber. I've installed it But I don't know how to launch it

Comment: you can either use your launch manager, be that `rofi` or `dmenu`, or you can type the viber launch command in a terminal

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `i3`, you have some sort of launch manager. By default, it is `dmenu`

> Aside from opening applications from a terminal, you can also use the handy dmenu which is opened by pressing $mod+d by default. Just type the name (or a part of it) of the application which you want to open.

(The same goes for `rofi`)

So you can use that to find viber and launch it. You can also just open a terminal and type the viber command and run it through there.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, Viber don't create any alias for running in PATH directories. So, for launching Viber I was create alias for Viber binary in any directory in PATH. After this any i3 app launcher (as dmenu or rofi) will find Viber and launch it